# From Ambari, Yarn fails to start with following error: ImportError: cannot import name yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari

When trying to start Yarn ResourceManager from Ambari, it keeps failing with following error.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/YARN/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 43, in 
   from yarn import yarn
ImportError: cannot import name yarn*

No error logged in Yarn Resourcemanager log.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the Ambari-agent cache.
On the yarn resourcemanager node, cleanup the cache and restart ambari agent to resolve the issue.

Stop Ambari agent as root:

*ambari-agent stop*

Take a backup of existing cache files:

*tar -czvf /tmp/cachebackup1.tar.gz /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/*

Remove existing cache:

*rm -rf /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/*

Start Ambari agent:

*ambari-agent start*